# Cant get Vue to focus on input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use `this.$refs.cInput.focus()` (`cInput` is a ref) and it's not working. I'd be able to hit `g` and the input should pop up and the cursor should focus in it, ready to input some data. It's showing but the focus part is not working. I get no errors in the console.

```
Vue.component('coordform', {
  template: `<form id="popup-box" @submit.prevent="process" v-show="visible"><input type="text" ref="cInput" v-model="coords" placeholder =""></input></form>`,
  data() {
    {
      return { coords: '', visible: false }
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.toggle)
  },
  mounted() {
  },
  updated() {
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.toggle)
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(e) {
      if (e.key == 'g') {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
        this.$refs.cInput.focus() //<--------not working
      }
    },
    process() {
        ...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm..interestingly it works when the input is outside of the form. I'll keep on troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok, it *works* if you wrap the focus call in a setTimeout of 0. I know it sounds hacky, but will that work for you? See my [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/81o7kq4k72)

Comment: @RichS thanks man, this works but is *mega* hacky. I'm not a purist, but care to explain how you came with this? Should I report this to the Vue guys?

Comment: I don't think it's a Vue-specific issue, but perhaps more in just the way in which the JS event loop works. I recalled this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) (but...I'm not entirely sure)

Comment: My guess is that when the form is being displayed again, the input textbox is still rendering while the focus() is called. Wrapping it in a setTimeout changes how that method is queued on the stack.

Comment: To answer your question thought, it still may be worth reporting to the VueJS guys, because people who use this framework won't want to code like this. I agree with you it's super hacky

Comment: Please don't. This is the expected behavior. You are asking Vue to update your DOM for you, and then before its update cycle has completed you are directly manipulating the DOM. Mixing the two is often necessary, but you can't assume that the instant the code `this.visible = !this.visible;` executes, that the input will be ready to accept focus.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I was unaware of `nextTick` (and it seems like the issue has been brought up with the vue team and [closed, with still some recent activity](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9200)). The function as an absolute last resort appears to use the least desirable approach of setTimeout.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `nextTick()` callback:

> When you set `vm.someData = 'new value'`, the component will not
> re-render immediately. It will update in the next “tick”, when the
> queue is flushed. [...]

> In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a data
> change, you can use `Vue.nextTick(callback)` immediately after the data
> is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been
> updated.
>
> ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue))

Use it in your toggle function like:

```js
methods: {
  toggle(e) {
    if (e.key == 'g') {
      this.visible = !this.visible;
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.cInput.focus())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, this works. But as-is, the form is filled with the g key the moment it shows up. Yes, it's focused, but how do i avoid the input being filled with the action key?

Answer (score 3):

In my case nextTick does not worked well.

I just used setTimeout like example below:

```
doSearch () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    if (this.$refs['search-input']) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$refs['search-input'].blur()
      }, 300)
    }
  })
},
```

I think that for your case code should be like below:

```
toggle(e) {
  if (e.key == 'g') {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    setTimeout(() => { this.$refs.cInput.focus() }, 300)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is only applicable on Vue3 but if you want to show focus on an input box from inside a component, it's best for you to setup a transition.  In the transition, there is an event called @after-enter.  So after the animation transition on enter is completed, the @after-enter is executed.  The @after-enter will be the event that will always get executed after your component shows up.

I hope this helps everyone who are having issues with the:

```
  ***this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.searchinput.focus());***
```

It may not be working the way you wanted it to because chances are the initial focus is still on the parent and the input element has not been displayed yet or if you placed it under mounted, it only gets executed once and no matter how you show/hide the component (via v-if or v-show), the nextTick line was already executed on mount() and doesn't get triggered on show of the component again.

Try this solution below:

```
<template>
   <transition name="bounce" @after-enter="afterEnter" >
     <div>
         <input type="text" ref="searchinput" />
     </div>
   </transition>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
       afterEnter() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                
                this.$refs.searchinput.focus();
                
            }, 200);
        },
}
</script>
```